# What's the name of this graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

[image: counterexample]

I saw this special graph is used in graph theory for a counterexample of several statements. 
But I don't remember the name of this graph.
Could you help me? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Grötzsch graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph) see for example [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroetzschGraph.html).
It is named after German mathematician Herbert Grötzsch.
The Grötzsch graph is the smallest triangle-free graph with $11$ vertices and chromatic number $4$.